# Help me make my Python 2 code work in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
import math,sys,time;i=0
while 1: sys.stdout.write("\r"+':(_​_)'[:3+int(round(math.sin(​i)))]+'n'+':(__)'[3+int(ro​und(math.sin(i))):]);sys.s​tdout.flush();time.sleep(.​15);i+=0.5*math.pi
```

I wrote that simple program in Python 2 a long time ago and it worked fine but it has syntax errors in Python 3. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me update it to be Python 3 compliant. Thanks.

Comment: was this for a code golf challenge?

Comment: i think you just have encoding issues (non-ascii characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pasted your code in a file, saved it, then opened it in a Python shell:

```
In [10]: f=open('test2.py')

In [11]: content=f.read()

In [12]: content
Out[12]: '#!/usr/bin/env python\n# coding: utf-8\n\nimport math,sys,time;i=0\nwhile 1: sys.stdout.write("\\r"+\':(_\xe2\x80\x8b_)\'[:3+int(round(math.sin(\xe2\x80\x8bi)))]+\'n\'+\':(__)\'[3+int(ro\xe2\x80\x8bund(math.sin(i))):]);sys.s\xe2\x80\x8btdout.flush();time.sleep(.\xe2\x80\x8b15);i+=0.5*math.pi\n'
```

Notice the `'\xe2\x80\x8b'` bytes sprinkled here and there. These are `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` characters encoded in utf-8:

```
In [24]: print(repr(u'\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}'.encode('utf-8')))
'\xe2\x80\x8b'
```

This is why your code is giving rise to SyntaxErrors.

Just retype it (or copy the code below) and it will run in Python3:

```
import math, sys, time; i=0
while 1: sys.stdout.write('\r'+':(__)'[:3+int(round(math.sin(i)))]+'n'+':(__)'[3+int(round(math.sin(i))):]); sys.stdout.flush(); time.sleep(0.15); i+=0.5*math.pi
```

Comment: You win the internet. Thank ya Sir.

Answer (score 1):

The problems has nothing to do with your Python version. You've got weird characters in your code.

I pasted it in [Metapad](http://liquidninja.com/metapad/) and a bunch of `?` showed up, I assume meaning unprintable character.

Just retype it and it will work fine, or find a text editor which will show those characters and delete them, or use Python to delete any non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, @agf is correct.  There was a weird character between the underscores in the first `(__)`.  Corrected (and works fine with Python 3):

```
import math,sys,time;i=0
while 1: sys.stdout.write("\r"+':(__)'[:3+int(round(math.sin(i)))]+'n'+':(__)'[3+int(round(math.sin(i))):]);sys.stdout.flush();time.sleep(.15);i+=0.5*math.pi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2to3 on your python installation.  It comes standard (I think) with 2.7.2+

Comment: I'm on winblows right now on Python 3.1 and I am unable to find it. Do you know what directory specifically it would be in?

Comment: @Joe Mas: It's installed in your Python installation under Tools\Scripts. On Unix it's installed as a separate command as well, so you just run 2to3, but under Windows I think you have to run python3 C:\WhereEverYourPythonIs\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py, but this may have changed under later versions.

Comment: Check out the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html.  Then it wouldn't be so confusing.